# How do I stop VSCode from revealing a file in the sidebar as soon as I click on it in "Source Control => Changes"

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I have a multiple file with changes in VSCode I often want to go trough the changes without staging.

I cannot do this because as soon as I click on one file with changes in "Source Control => Changes" the file is revealed in the sidebar and I have to navigate back to "Source Control" to review the changes of another file. In the past this wasn't the case. In order to open the file regularly (without diff) I could manually go to the Explorer and the file was selected.

When files are staged I can click on them and they will not be revealed in the sidebar. This behavior is what I would also like to have for files that are not staged.

What is causing this behavior (I use VSCode v1.74.2)? In the past this wasn't the case.

**Update**: This behavior is caused by an extension I need (Sigasi). They made an update and for some reason this caused the described unwanted behavior.

Comment: I tried in VSC Insiders 1.75 and the behavior is still as months ago, if you select a file in SCM bar it shows a diff. What do you mean with `revealed in the sidebar`?

Comment: VSCode will automatically navigate from the "Source Control" tab to the "Explorer" tab and the file will be selected.

Comment: it has never done that and also not in v1.75. Disable all your extensions or try in Insiders version without additional extensions

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I disabled my extensions one after another and found the extension causing this unwanted behavior.

Comment: I will leave this question unanswered. I need the extension for my work (Sigasi) but I don't know to fix this unwanted behavior without disabling the extension.

Comment: I don't think so. This is between you and Sigasi. There's no Stack Overflow question to answer here (and this is not your personal blog).

Comment: Make a request at Sigasi to remove this behavior, it is not standard VSC behavior, and also annoying, to bring the explorer to front when clicking in the SCM bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello from the Sigasi support department. ;)

The [Sigasi extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Sigasi.sigasi-vscode) comes with a dedicated Project View to bring some useful Eclipse File System features to our VS Code extension.
One of the features this Project View offers, is to link the Project View with the editor in focus. This allows to quickly spot where you are in the project file hierarchy.

This feature can easily be disabled by going to the Project View and clicking the icon that controls the link with the editor. I'm linking a [screenshot showing the link with editor setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzCMC.png).

It seems this feature at the moment is more intrusive than intended. We plan to adjust this feature so that it isn't active if the Project View is not visible or collapsed.